# Screeching sound at slow drive and breaking

Tags: brakes, mazda, noise, chassis

I have 2 questions actually. But I feel there might be connection so I decided to combine this 2 queries.

**First:** During slow start drive I hear this low screeching sound like something is loose. I'm trying to figure out where it is coming from but it is hard since the sound is produced only while the vehicle is moving. I know I need to check and tighten bolts somewhere but if someone can provide me the major points to check so that I can little by little check which caused the screeching. My car is Mazda 323F 2000 Model AT.

**Second:** I recently brought this up to a couple of mechanic already. This happens when I slightly press the break pedal during slow drive on traffic moving to a stop (or if the vehicle is slow moving). The break would screech loud. I checked the break pads and it is still thick and I see no damage on the disk and drums as well. The mechanic also said that this is normal for automatic vehicle? I think otherwise. If anyone can give me suggestion on how to avoid this loud screeching sound that would be great. Also is there a possibility that this and my first question is somehow related?

I know this might be too broad but maybe you gurus can help me try something to narrow the possibilities down.

Comment: Did you check the inside brake pad? They can and do wear at different rates.

Comment: Take the car to a reputable mechanic. This is a brakes issue and something you should not dwell on.

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I've checked the inner pad and it is ok. Another mechanic told me that the disk break is hard and to remove the noise,  I need to replace it. I have not tried replacing the disk breaks though to confirm. Well I think it possible. Since it only occurs during start up.

Comment: My car has the exact same issue at the front passenger side but had numerous mechanics check brakes and everything is fine

Answer (score 2):

This definitely sounds like some brake pads are worn down to the indicator wear bar. It is supposed to make a screeching noise when this happens. Don't take the car back to the mechanic who said this was normal for an automatic! But do take it to a reputable shop for another opinion. And yes, both points of your question are probably due to the same condition.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if it's coming from the front or rear? Also double check your serpentine or v-belts... They may be loose or just need some belt dressing. I know they can sound like that when at idle or when stopping.

Comment: For the loud screech when breaking, it comes from the front break I guess. But for the low screeching sound, I think it is from the rear but I am not sure. I will try my best to locate the source.